# Create custom mobile wallet for my two ERC20 Tokens

Tags: tokens, erc-20, wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, mobile-wallet

I have two ERC20 tokens that I created on Ethereum.
I would like to know if it is possible for me to create a mobile application that will allow my users to check their balance (for tokens) and transfer them tokens, a kind of wallet app, if possible with multisig functionality...

Comment: You have a wallet for android https://github.com/walleth/walleth which is open source

Comment: It does not correspond to what i want

Answer (score 1):

Sure it's possible. A very basic wallet is simply an interface to the blockchain. On top of that you can add multiple features (such as multisig, sending transactions, ...)

What you need is:

1) Code for the wallet

2) A node to connect to to get access to the blockchain

However I don't recommend writing a wallet by yourself as it's very risky and easy to make mistakes. Such mistakes may cause you and your customers to lose all their assets somewhere in the future. If you google you can probably find existing open source wallets for almost any language you prefer - also mobile.

Comment: I already have a mobile application with some features, to which I would like to add the ERC20 token wallet feature.
I can't use an existing application like Wallet....
However I will still try to look for open source wallet applications because so far I have not found anything conclusive.